# It won’t let me change the file name variables.scss to variables.css

Tags: conemu

I'm using Conemu, and I’ve installed everything from zsh to sass.

I'm trying to convert `variables.scss` to `variables.css`, so I type this command:

```
sass variables.scss:variables.css
```

But I get an error

> Errno:ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - variables.scss

Comment: Why you've tag that with "conemu"? Your question is about sass and zsh. ConEmu does not provide any of that with its installer.